# Do we have evidence of the transition from -mentum to -ment?

Tags: english, latin, french, history

Several English words end in *-ment*: augment, document, movement, moment, segment, etc.

According to several dictionaries, the English *-ment* suffix is in many cases traced to the French *-ment*, which in turn is said to derive from Latin *-mentum*.

**Do we have any evidence as for when and why the shift from *-mentum* to *-ment* happened?**

Clarification: What do I mean with *evidence* here? I'm defining it very broad. Being a beginner in linguistics, my aim is to understand if we know the big picture of roughly when and how the shift happened. Some methods of etymology research are listed in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology#Methods).

Comment: Well, the final nasal sound was lost really early in vulgar latin. French lost maaaany final vowels so it is a very simple phenomenon. I think a historical linguist who studies French could easly tell an approximate time period!

Comment: @ErgativeMan Interesting! According to Wiktionary, _-mentum_ was pronounced [ˈmɛn̪t̪ʊ̃ˑ] in Classical Latin and [ˈmɛn̪t̪um] in later Ecclesiastical Latin. This makes me wonder: how was it pronounced in Vulgar Latin? Also, how we know these things?

Comment: We know via reconstruction based on the descendents, spelling at that time etc. I think it depends on when and where a specific variety of vulgar latin was spoken, but we know, mainly via misspellings and texts by "grammar nazis" of that time that this disappearance of a final nasal sound was a very common process in the latin speaking area.

Comment: Another good clue is the fact that the words in modern romance languages come from the accusative case which usualy had a -um, -am, -em ending and now they don't have this final nasal sound anymore.

Comment: @ErgativeMan with the final -m we also know from poetic metre. Final -Vm is scanned as a light syllable, as if there was no final consonant (if the following word begins in a cluster, it might scan as heavy, likely by resyllabifying the start of the next word as a coda of the first). Iirc final -Vm can participate in synalepha, just as vowel final words can. All this indicates the -m was not an actual consonant in this position, but the fact it was written at all, even in many graffiti, indicates there was some sound indicated. Nasalisation is the only plausible option

Comment: Yes! That's why I called a "nasal sound" instead of [m], this feature disappeared

Comment: What sort of evidence are you looking for here?

Comment: @Draconis Good question. Intuitively, for example, earliest textual attestations for -ment instead of -mentum, either in French or Colloquial Latin. Another possibility are theories of language evolution with pointers to observations in today's languages that might corroborate this. I'm trying to understand the big picture here of when and why these changes happened.

Comment: @Draconis I further clarified the question. Thankyou for helping me sharpen my thinking here.